# MongoDB data archive strategy

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, database-administration, database-backups

I need all your expert advise on this topic. I have mongodb cluster where 10 million documents are stored and at some point I dont need all those 10 million actively. But I still need my application to have access to that data, so that if someone clicks on any link on web, it will pull up the data from these old documents.

I understand, I can host a separate instance/cluster and ship the old documents there and change my application logic so that it will talk to both the database. But I am looking for more efficient solution where, I can do archiving and still have access to these old documents.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

There would be tow Options coming to my mind:

- Move the archived documents to a seperate collection, which is programmatically close to a seperate DB instance, but ou would most likely use the same access keys, etc. so a little less effort
- Or you add an `isArchived` flag to your document schema and when querying data select all elements where isArchived is not set to `true` , e.g. 
  `db.yourCollection.find( {isArchived: {$eq: false} })`